# Как распарсить sqlite без дополнительных библиотек?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Нужно анализировать базу данных sqlite. Пишу на c# в visual studio 2013 в Windows 7. 
Использовал стороннюю библиотеку, но она весит 3 мб, а мне очень важен размер.
Как можно читать бд sqlite без использования сторонних библиотек? Может в visual studio есть встроенный класс? 
Я пробовал использовать обычный sql, но у меня не получилось. 
У меня сыпется программа на этой этом моменте:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, m_dbConn);
adapter.Fill(dTable);
```

Comment: Кхм, а то что сам .Net-фреймворк весит сотни мегабайт вас не смущает?

Comment: sqlite под .Net есть в разных форматах. У меня тройка сборок лежит, около 2мб в сумме занимают. Если выкинуть поддержку х64 - меньше мб выйдет. А куда вы так экономите?

Comment: В данном контексте нет такого понятия как "обычный sql". К БД нужно обращаться через провайдер. Для SqlServer свой, для Oracle - свой, для Sqlite - как это неудивительно - свой. Загляните в [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) по `SqlDataAdapter` - там прямо написано, что он для  SqlServer. Так что ставьте провайдер для sqlite и не страдайте фигнёй.